# Found Output from three tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have three tables. 1. Emp, 2. Salary, 3. Commison.
EMP table have four column i.e.

```
ID        Name      Gender  department.
101     Tarun        M        10
102     Sahil        M        10
103     Manju        F        10
104     Dipika       F        10
105     Parvinder    M        20
106     Akhilesh     M        20
107     Shanti       F        20
108     Shivani      F        30
109     Bhuvan       M        30
110     babita       F        30
```

Salary table have two column i.e

```
ID       Salary . 
101      3000
102      5420
103      8954 
104      10000 
105      8574
106      9965
107      9000
108      7500
109      9658 
110      9800
```

Commison Table have two column i.e.

```
ID    Commission.
101      2500
104      2000
107      3000 
109      5000
```

Output will Be

```
ID       Name         Salary+Commision

101     Tarun              5500     
102     Sahil              5420
103     Manju              8954    
104     Dipika             12000   
105     Parvinder          8574     
106     Akhilesh           9965     
107     Shanti             12000    
108     Shivani            7500    
109     Bhuvan             14658 
110     babita             9800
```

Comment: Thanks but error exixt "  LEFT JOIN Salary_new S on E.ID = S.ID
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Answer (score 1):

Your query will look like this:

```
select e.id, e.name, s.salary + c.Commission as total
from salary s,
     Commission c,
     emp e
where e.id = s.id
  and c.id = s.id
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Yes. But I am more comfortable with not to use 'Join', at-least for simple joining of tables.

Comment: I used to do the same, but after switching I'll never go back!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you would simply do the following:

```
SELECT 
E.ID
,E.Name
,S.Salary + C.Commission
FROM Emp E
LEFT JOIN Salary S on E.ID = S.ID
LEFT JOIN Commission C on E.ID = C.ID
```

Comment: Thanks but error came "                                                                    LEFT JOIN Salary_new S on E.ID = S.ID
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Can you paste the exact query you tried to execute?

Comment: 1  SELECT
  2  E.ID
  3  ,S.Salary + C.Comm
  4  FROM Emp_new E
  5  LEFT JOIN Salary_new S on E.ID = S.ID
  6* LEFT JOIN Comm_new C on E.ID = C.ID
  7  /
LEFT JOIN Salary_new S on E.ID = S.ID
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Name, s.Salary + c.Commission AS Total FROM EMP e 
INNER JOIN Salary s ON e.ID = s.ID
INNER JOIN Commison c ON s.ID = c.ID
```

Comment: inner join only give the result of employee having commision only

Comment: Thanks Dear Vinoth for reply but error came  "INNER JOIN Salary_new s ON e.ID = s.ID
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: SELECT E.ID,S.Salary + C.Comm  FROM Emp_new E  LEFT JOIN Salary_new S on E.ID = S.ID  LEFT JOIN Comm_new C on E.ID = C.ID
LEFT JOIN Salary_new S on E.ID = S.ID
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 0):

Considering every employee has their entry in salary table,

```
SELECT 
E.ID as ID
,E.Name as Name
,nvl(S.Salary,0) + nvl(C.Commission,0) as "Salary+Commision"
FROM Emp E INNER JOIN Salary S on E.ID = S.ID
LEFT JOIN Commission C on E.ID = C.ID
```

In case you think their might be some employee whose record are not loaded in salary table but you want them in your result.

```
SELECT 
E.ID as ID,E.Name as Name,nvl(S.Salary,0) + nvl(C.Commission,0) as "Salary+Commision"
FROM Emp E LEFT JOIN Salary S on E.ID = S.ID
LEFT JOIN Commission C on E.ID = C.ID
```

In case you dont want to write "JOIN" -

```
SELECT 
E.ID as ID
,E.Name as Name
,nvl(S.Salary,0) + nvl(C.Commission,0) as "Salary+Commision"
FROM Emp E ,Salary S,Commission C
WHERE E.ID = S.ID(+)
AND E.ID = C.ID(+)
```

Anything you can do but handle NULL value coming from **Commision** table as every employee will not be getting commision.